# Android : CSV not storing values in normal format

Tags: android

I am trying to store values in csv file. But it is storing all those values in exponential format.

FileOutputStream fos;

```
   try {  
        File dir = new File("/sdcard/");  
        boolean b = dir.mkdir();
        File myFile = new File(dir, filename); 
        myFile.createNewFile();  
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile); 
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        for (String s : arrayListDGId) {
           myOutWriter.append(s + "\n"); 
        }                     
          myOutWriter.close();  
          fOut.close();
```

These are the example values of arraylist 10989808,8768762,76876787. But it stores/converts those values in exponential form like 1E+9, 8E+8 & so on format. I want to store those in there normal/original format. Plz help me

Comment: what is arrayListDGId

Comment: It contains string values like 978379281,999423424, 121232323

Comment: It can't contain "978379281" as a String because then it would write it as the String. Somewhere before you do the conversion to String and that code is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array contains ints like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayListDGId
```

You can write it like this:

```
for (Integer i : arrayListDGId) {
       myOutWriter.append(String.format("%d%n", i)); 
}
```

For more Information on how to format numbers look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: I tried above one but it is still storing values in exponential format.

Comment: For example, I stored 76658758777698 as an integer but when i opened my csv then it is showing this format 7.66588E+13. I need it in its original format. So above solution is not working for me. Plz suggest something different. I already tried this for integer/long/string data types but none of these working.